# Google script Web App importing html from library

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I'im trying to do the following:

I have my working Google web app with the following script and of course a page.html

```
function getHtmlBlob() {
  //Logger.log(e.parameter);
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page");
  var htmlBody = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
  Logger.log(htmlBody);
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(htmlBody, MimeType.HTML);
  return blob;
}

function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log(e.parameter);
  var blob = getHtmlBlob();
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(blob);
}
```

I would like to release a library with the page.html and the first function, link the library in the webApp as "Lib" and have the doGet as follows

```
function doGet(e) {
  //Logger.log(e.parameter);
  //var body = Lib.getHtmlBlob();
  var body = Lib.getHtmlBlob().evaluate();
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(body);
}
```

but it is not working and I'm obtaining the text of the getHtmlBlob function instead of the web page when running my webApp (so at least, there is some link). This is not working with and without the .evaluate() after calling the function.

This is what I see executing the WebApp

[image: Executing the WebApp only shows the code as text]

Is this not possible, or did I make some mistake?
The target is: releasing my webApp and

1. do not have the page.html file visible (if possibile!)
2. share an unique page.html for multiple webapps like a library

I've worked a long with GAS libraries, but only for "protecting" script functions until now. Thank you for any tips

Comment: About `This is not working with and withoud the .evaluate() after calling the function.`, in your script, I think that when you modify `var body = Lib.getHtmlBlob().evaluate();` to `var body = Lib.getHtmlBlob();`, the HTML from the library is opened. So, I cannot understand your situation. I apologize for this situation. For example, when you modify the script of `doGet(e)`, did you reflect the latest script to the Web Apps? I'm worried about it.

Comment: @Tanaike I've update the question with a screenshoot. But your comment made me think and I manage to make it work but still can't understand the problem, it seems that is about release versions of both Lib and the webApp

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I manage to make it work`, I understood that your issue was resolved. About your updated question, in order to replicate `This is what I see executing the WebApp`, I think that when `var body = Lib.getHtmlBlob().evaluate();` is modified to `var body = Lib.getHtmlBlob;`, the same result occurs.

Comment: In the case of Web Apps, when you modify the script of Web Apps on the client side, it is required to reflect the latest script to Web Apps. On the other hand, in the case of the library, when you install the library as the latest version, even when the script of the library is modified, it is not required to reflect the latest script to Web Apps on the client side. This can be also seen on [my report](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/e46def22cf106b012dfa5ad359b93d24). It seems that this is the current specification. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike I manage to see a rendered html page :) thank you, I will test the thing more to identify what the problem was. It seems it started working after creating a release version of the Lib (and not working with the only HEAD version... but reverting it now works even with HEAD)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue is resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: @Tanaike I will back to this weekend project soon, I will sure post an answer when I will know for sure what the problem was

Answer (score 0):

The answer, after many test, seems to be:

1. Implement [Tanaike's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77972913/google-script-web-app-importing-html-from-library#comment137462148_77972913)
2. Be aware of the following:

- If you want to fetch a GAS Library in your WebApp you can as usual
- You don't need to have the library deployed, it will work in HEAD version also

But

- you must deploy first your "main" script as WebApp
- you will able to see modifications of your Lib code as long as you reference the HEAD version of the library (as usual)
- you will NOT be able to see any modifications of your "main" Web App code even if working with the /dev link (never experienced in other Web Apps before).

So **before the Release you must be careful of mismatching calls**, typos and other errors between the main and the library code. For further lines of code or correction in the main Web App code a new release is needed.

In my case, I was trying to align a both a typo and the Tanaike suggestion AFTER the release and expecting it working with a /dev link.

I move most of the code in the library, so this is the library side

```
function getHtmlBlob() 
{
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page");
  //other code here
  var htmlBody = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(htmlBody, MimeType.HTML);

  return blob;
}
```

and this is the Web App "main" side

```
function doGet(e) 
{ 
    var body = Lib.getHtmlBlob();
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(body);
}
```

Thank you @Tanaike